# Blender Animation or Physics?

Tags: animation, physics

So i see this video here where the character leafs move with the character https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PunVHiOxUEk&t=902s

In blender is there any physics that can achieve this effect? or would you just have to animate the leaf with the motion?

Sorry for the noob question but want to start learning some of this animation

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: You can do both.

Comment: what physic would i be looking at? im trying to find some sort of tutorial but i havent touched physics yet and dont know what im looking for

Comment: rigid body physics or soft body physics.